# Disable cell interaction while showing the selection indicator

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Tried using `[self.myTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];`
 to make the cell show the selection indicator, but once I add `cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;`, the selection indicator stops showing.
Is there a way to make the cell look selected, grayed out, and doesn't respond to taps?

Comment: Why can't you just ignore the event when this kind of cell is selected in `didSelectRow:atIndexPath:`?

Answer (score 0):

Put this line under: cellForRowAtIndexPath.

```
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```